# Multiplicacion y suma en MySql o php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

necesito realizar la siguiente operación de la siguiente tabla en mysql o php:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito calcular valor_unitario por cantidad (valor_unitario * cantidad) y sumar todos los valores cuando el no_recibo sea igual a 11 (where no_recibo = 11).

Necesito saber como puedo realizar dicha consulta en MySql o como puedo hacerla en PHP para almacenarla en una variable.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Usando MySQL

La consulta podría escribirse usando **[`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)**.

Se trata de una función de agregación que :

- Devuelve la suma de la expresión o columna indicada.
- Si el conjunto de devoluciones no tiene filas, `SUM()` devuelve `NULL`.
- La palabra clave `DISTINCT` puede usarse para sumar solamente los valores distintos de la expresión o columna.
- Si no hay filas coincidentes, `SUM()` devuelve `NULL`.

La consulta se escribiría así más o menos:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(cantidad*valor_unitario) total 
    FROM calcular_20170906 
    WHERE no_recibo=11 
;
```

#### <kbd>[VER DEMO REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/UMF10589)</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS calcular_20170906 (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    no_recibo INT,
    cantidad INT,
    valor_unitario DECIMAL(12,2)
);

INSERT INTO calcular_20170906 (no_recibo, cantidad, valor_unitario)
    VALUES 
        (10,1,6000),
        (11,1,50000),
        (11,1,10000),
        (11,2,100000)
;

SELECT 
    SUM(cantidad*valor_unitario) total 
    FROM calcular_20170906 
    WHERE no_recibo=11 
;
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
total
260000,00
```

---

#### Usando PHP

Tendrías que obtener todas las filas, sin usar `GROUP BY` o agruparlas combinando `GROUP BY` y `GROUP_CONCAT` y luego recorrer las valores e irlos sumando.

En mi opinión no merece la pena, si sólo necesitas el total.

Comment: Cedano, sinceramente eres muy bueno en esto, tengo una consulta SELECT SUM(cantidad*valor_unitario) FROM producto_alquilado WHERE no_recibo=11 sin usar el group by y me arroja el resultado, crees que esta bien si lo uso asi?

Comment: Oh claro que sí @ByGroxD se me escapó esa. En realidad `SUM` es una función de agrupación, como lo es `GROUP_BY`, así que en este caso `GROUP_BY` no es necesario. Ahora edito.